# What is this phishing technique called using subdomains

Tags: phishing, terminology, dns-domain, sub-domain

I'm writing a blog post analyzing a list of phishing domains and I'm coming across a lot of IDN homograph attack domains and these "subdomain attack domains" but I cannot find the technical/good way to describe it.

For example, this type of domain is used to phish microsoft login details

```
login.microsoft.com.account.auth.redacted.com
```

How would you describe/categorize that style of attack with the same calibre of IDN homograph attack? The best I've come up with is "subdomain attack" but I don't think it makes sense in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDN homograph attack is not correct. Although the idea of this type of attack is exploiting the fact that many different characters look alike, it still allows for subdomains.

> In the Domain Name System (DNS) hierarchy, a subdomain is a domain that is a part of a main domain. [Subdomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain).

Despite this, do not be confused. We are treating the whole address as resolving to an IP address in this scenario. E.g. localhost -> 127.0.0.1, equally login.microsoft.com.example.com -> 127.0.0.1.

What you are describing *login.microsoft.com.example.com* is [deceptive phishing](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/email-security/what-is-phishing.html). Some web browsers will highlight the subdomain leaving the domain grey. E.g. ***login.microsoft.com***.example.com

Comment: To assist with writing your article and categorising further see URL and the notes at the bottom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing